# Downloading Image from json url doesn't work

Tags: json, swift, swiftui, urlsession

I'm trying to get some data from a json Api and display this data along with an image. First I have a function that fetches the data from the Api, then I have another function that downloads the image data. The problem is that the second function doesn't seem to be working right and the image data is never recieved.

```
func fetchAPI() {

        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, error) in

    /* Code that decodes the json and gets the imageURL string */

                DispatchQueue.main.async {

                    self.downloadImage(url: imageURL) // call the function that downloads the imageData
                }
            } catch {
                print("Error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
            }
        }
        .resume()
    }
```

The function that downloads the image:

```
func downloadImage(url: String) {

        guard let imageURL = URL(string: url) else {
            print("Error: Invalid image URL")
            return
        }
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: imageURL) { data, response, error in
            guard let recievedData = data, error == nil  else {
                print("Error: No Data")
                return
            }
                        print("Got Data") // Doesn't output to console
                        print(recievedData) // Doesn't output to console
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.imageData = recievedData <- Nothing
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: `resume()` isn't called in `downloadImage(url:)`. So url task isn't started.

Comment: Thanks. But is what I'm doing here is considered good practice? or is there a better way to do it? I'm using (SwiftUI)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Call .resume()

```
func downloadImage(url: String) {

        guard let imageURL = URL(string: url) else {
            print("Error: Invalid image URL")
            return
        }
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: imageURL) { data, response, error in
            guard let recievedData = data, error == nil  else {
                print("Error: No Data")
                return
            }
                        print("Got Data") // Doesn't output to console
                        print(recievedData) // Doesn't output to console
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.imageData = recievedData <- Nothing
            }
        }
        .resume()
    }
```

Comment: Thanks. But is what I'm doing here is considered good practice? or is there a better way to do it? I'm using (SwiftUI)